# g++: error: unrecognized option ‘--end-group’

Tags: g++

I had been using ubuntu 10.10 for quite some time as my development PC. My code was to build without error with g++ version 4.4.5. Recently I had upgraded my system to 11.10 which has come with g++ version 4.6.1
Now , using this compiler, when I am trying to build the same piece of code, I am getting this error:

```
g++: error: unrecognized option ‘--end-group’
```

The Make file line, where this error is thrown is:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
g++ $(LDFLAGS) $^ $ -Wl,--start-group $(ARCHIVE_LIBS) --end-group -o $(TARGET)
cp -f $(TARGET) ../../../bin/
```

Can some please throw some light on this? I had googled but I did not get any clue?

Thanks and Regards,
Souvik

Answer (score 10):

`--end-group` is a linker flag so you should prefix it with `-Wl`, i.e.

```
g++ $(LDFLAGS) $^ $ -Wl,--start-group $(ARCHIVE_LIBS) -Wl,--end-group -o $(TARGET)
```

I am not sure why this worked before.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html (Point No.2)
GCC 4.6 changelog explains. It has become STRICTER :-)

Comment: @smRaj: That makes perfect sense, and thanks for actually studying the Changelog.