# Undefined reference to 'malloc' and more

Tags: gcc, riscv

When I try to complile the dhrystone benchmark, it shows the following errors:

```
xilinx@pynq:~/dhrystone$ riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -Os -ffreestanding -nostdlib -o out.elf -Wl,-Bstatic,-T,picorv32.ld dhry_1.o dhry_2.o init.o -lgcc -march=rv32im

/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: dhry_1.o: in function `Proc_1':
dhry_1.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `memcpy'
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: dhry_1.c:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `memcpy'
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: dhry_1.o: in function `main':
dhry_1.c:(.text.startup+0x3c): undefined reference to `malloc'
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: dhry_1.c:(.text.startup+0x4c): undefined reference to `malloc'
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: dhry_1.c:(.text.startup+0x84): undefined reference to `strcpy'
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: dhry_1.c:(.text.startup+0x98): undefined reference to `strcpy'
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: dhry_1.c:(.text.startup+0xb8): undefined reference to `time'
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: dhry_1.c:(.text.startup+0xf0): undefined reference to `strcpy'
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: dhry_1.c:(.text.startup+0x184): undefined reference to `time'
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: dhry_1.c:(.text.startup+0x254): undefined reference to `strcpy'
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: dhry_2.o: in function `.L15':
dhry_2.c:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `strcmp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that all the missing functions are from stdih.h. But I don't know how to fix it.

heres the commands I used to compile the benchmark.

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -c -Qn -DSTKPTR=32768 -march=rv32im -o init.o -Os --std=c99 init.S 
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -c -Qn -march=rv32im -o dhry_1.o -Os --std=c99 dhry_1.c
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -c -Qn -march=rv32im -o dhry_2.o -Os --std=c99 dhry_2.c

riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -Os -ffreestanding -nostdlib -o out.elf -Wl,-Bstatic,-T,picorv32.ld init.o dhry_1.o dhry_2.o -lgcc -march=rv32im
riscv32-unknown-elf-objcopy -O binary out.elf out.bin
```

Can anyone help me pls. Thanks for any help.

With the help of @yflelion, i've changed the fifth line to the following,

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -Os -ffreestanding -nostdlib -o out.elf -Wl,-Bstatic,-T,picorv32.ld init.o dhry_1.o dhry_2.o -lgcc -lc -lgloss -march=rv32im
```

And it shows the following errors,

```
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: /opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/libgloss.a(sys_gettimeofday.o): in function `.L5':
sys_gettimeofday.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `__errno'
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: /opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/libgloss.a(sys_sbrk.o): in function `.L7':
sys_sbrk.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `__errno'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

with the following command,

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -Os -ffreestanding -nostdlib -o out.elf -Wl,-Bstatic,-T,picorv32.ld init.o dhry_1.o dhry_2.o -lgcc -lc -march=rv32im
```

it shows the following errors,

```
/opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: /opt/riscv32im/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): in function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
```

Comment: Maybe remove the `-nostdlib` argument?

Comment: Try adding `-specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs` along with others. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use nostdlib, the compiler not use the standard system startup files or libraries when linking.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html
The only library you are linking against by using your command line is libgcc, but you are using functions from libc. you need to add -lc and most likely -lgloss. be careful with circular dependencies ( --start-group --end-group).
You can add the -v option and compile a minimalist example with the default options to see how it is done by default.
If there is no reason why you cannot use libc and libgloss by default, it is better to remove nostdlib option.

To compile your example try:

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -Os -ffreestanding -nostdlib -o out.elf -Wl,-Bstatic,-T,picorv32.ld init.o dhry_1.o dhry_2.o -lgcc -lc -lgloss -lc -march=rv32im
```

But the best solution to avoid circular dependencies would be:

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -Os -ffreestanding -nostdlib -o out.elf -Wl,-Bstatic,-T,picorv32.ld init.o dhry_1.o dhry_2.o -lgcc --start-group -lc -lgloss --end-group -lgcc -march=rv32im
```

Comment: hi, when I add -lc and -lgloss to the command, it shows another error msgs, undefined reference to `__errno'

Comment: how did you give the libraries to gcc? can you show your command line?  i think it a circular dependence problem .

Comment: The deatiled command and error messages were added above

Comment: Before `--start-group` and `--end-group` flags, it needs `-Wl` prefix, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585428/g-error-unrecognized-option-end-group/8585628#8585628

Comment: As per yflelion 1st instructions add -lgcc -lc -lgloss -lc (note the extra -lc)